# Angular 2 : How to get params on resolve

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Routs Strategy:

```
export const routes = [
{
    path       : 'rto-activation/:id',
    component  : RtoActivationComponent,
    resolve  : {
        'singleRto': SingleRtoResolve
    },
    children   : [
        {path: 'start', component: ActivationStartComponent},
        {path: 'warning', component: WarningComponent},
        {path: 'confirm', component: ConfirmRtoDetailsComponent},
        {path: 'ldWaiver', component: LDWaiverComponent},
        {path: 'payment-schedule', component: PaymentScheduleComponent},
        {path: 'user-reference', component: ReferenceComponent}

    ]
}
```

SingleRtoResolve:

```
constructor(private router: Router,
            private route: ActivatedRoute) {
}

resolve() {
    var self = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        self.subscription = self.route.params.subscribe(
            (param: any) => {
                let id = param[ 'id' ];
               self.rtoService.getRto(null, +id)
                .then((res: any) => {
                    resolve(res)
                })

            });
    });
    }
```

I Know: We usually get params from ActivatedRoute service.

Question: Can i get params from Router service.

Brief: Trying to get route params on Resolve Injectable because on that stage route is not actived and i am unable to get params.

Usecase: When a user opens any child routes(implicity and explicitly)with some (:id) so data should be resolved in parent routes.

Get Params successfully when route is actived in any child component:

```
ngOnInit() {
let self          = this;
this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe(
    (param: any) => {
        let id = param[ 'id' ];
        self.rtoService.getRto(null, +id)
            .then((res: any) => {

            })

    });
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Your `SingleRtoResolve` should `implements Resolve<T>`. Then you'll just need your data service (`RtoService`i guess) in your `constructor() {}`. No need for the `Router` or the `ActivatedRoute` here since your `resolve()` will get a `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` and a `RouterStateSnapshot`.
So the `resolve()` will look smth like that:

```
  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Promise<any> {
    return ...
  }
```

..and you can just use `route.params['id']`to get your id.

---

*Edit:* You can also check the docs for the **[Resolve](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Resolve-interface.html)**

Comment: Using route.params.id leads to an another error
  "Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: any; }'."
Angular -shared.d.ts
export declare type Params = {
    [key: string]: any;
};

Comment: Did you try it with `route.params['id']` then?

Comment: Glad you've got it working :-) also the type error should vanish when you use the `['id']`

Answer (score 0):

**We need to pass dependence in resolver method instead of constructor**

```
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {

    console.log(route.params);// you can see the log and use it

    return this.apiService.getItems(route.params.params1).catch(() => {
       return Observable.empty();
    });
  }
```